# Datasource query meaning found in sitecore presentation component

Tags: sql, sitecore, components, presentation

What does +custom :- templatename | event mean?

This is found in datasource in presentation component in sitecore

Comment: PLEASE add more details

Answer (score 1):

It is a search query.  That component must use a search-based datasource.

See this blog: http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/sitecore-7-development-team/posts/2013/04/sitecore-7-datasources.aspx

Comment: What does templatename | event mean?

Comment: It means it's looking for items based on the event template